# Mostrar buffer de Node.js a tiempo real en un navegador

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy intentando hacer en Node.js un programa que, tras recibir un comando tipo Unix via `POST`, este lo ejecute y muestre **a tiempo real** la salida en el navegador.

Este es el código que estoy empleando para ejecutar los comandos:

```
 exec(myCommand, function(err, stdout, stderr){
     sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
     sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr);
         if(err !== null) {
             console.log('EXECUTION ERROR: ' , err);
         }
 }
```

Sin embargo, la salida de `stdout` viene en forma de `Buffer`, por lo que no tengo muy claro cómo puedo hacer que el navegador vaya mostrando su contenido, a medida que aumenta.

Mi idea es que si, por ejemplo, ejecuto el comando `apt-get update`, vaya mostrando qué está haciendo a tiempo real, y no toda la salida de golpe cuando ya ha terminado.

Se me ha ocurrido que podría guardar el contenido del buffer en una cadena de texto repetidamente, y luego hacer que el navegador, a través de JavaScript, fuese comprobando las actualizaciones con frecuencia, pero me parece una solución un poco chapucera, por no mencionar que no es tan rápida como me gustaría.

En conclusión, ¿cómo puedo hacer esto de la manera más rápida y simple posible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que la salida se vaya mostrando a medida que va saliendo y no de golpe debes usar `spawn` en lugar de usar `exec`. Creo que se ajusta más a lo que quieres lograr. Si quieres entender la diferencia entre las dos funciones puedes visitar [este enlace](http://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html).

Para que se muestre en tiempo real debes usar `socket.io`, es mucho más fiable que usar peticiones GET a intervalos para obtener lo que está imprimiendo el comando y puedes usarlo como transporte para comenzar a ejecutarlos.

Aquí te pongo un demo que envia los comandos desde cualquier cliente y la salida se refleja en todos los otros que estan conectados. Yo envío el comando usando el mismo socket pero tu puedes modificarlo y usar POST si quieres.

Como no especificas si se pueden usar otros frameworks lo use usando solo node.js y socket.io.

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
url = require('url'),
child = require('child_process');

var fileStream = fs.readFileSync('cmd.html'),
    myCommand = 'cmd.exe',
    myArgs = ['/?'];

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (url.parse(req.url).pathname === '/') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end(fileStream);
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Not found');
    }
}).listen(3000);

function executeCommand(command, args) {
    var toExec = command || myCommand,
        theArgs = args ? args : (command ? [] : myArgs);

    var cmd = child.spawn(toExec, theArgs);
    cmd.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        io.emit('output', data.toString());
    });

    cmd.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
         io.emit('output', data.toString());
    });

    cmd.on('error', function (err) {
        io.emit('output', err.message);
    });

    cmd.on('close', function (code) {
       io.emit('Process exited with code ' + code);
    });
 }

 var io = require('socket.io')(server);

 io.on('connection', function(socket) {
     socket.on('command', function(cmd) {
         var c = cmd.split(' ');
        executeCommand(c[0], c.slice(1));
    });
});

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

Y este es el fichero `cmd.html` que se envía al cliente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Live command</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dashboard"
 style="width: 100%; height: 300px; overflow: auto; background-color: black; color: white; border: gray solid 3px">
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 30px">
        <label  for="command">Command:</label>
        <input id="command" type="text">
        <button id="send" type="button">Execute</button>
    </div>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
            var console = document.getElementById('dashboard');
            var button = document.getElementById('send');
            var command = document.getElementById('command');

            socket.on('output', function (data) {
                var newLine = document.createElement('p');
                newLine.innerHTML = data;
                console.appendChild(newLine);
            });

            button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                socket.emit('command', command.value);
            });
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No tengo ningún problema en usar frameworks adicionales, aunque me gustaría saber (por mera curiosidad) cómo funciona. ¿Se crea una conexión entre cliente y servidor, que se mantiene abierta hasta que termina de transmitirse la información?

Comment: Puedes revisar los detalles en http://socket.io/ pero imagino que es igual que todos los frameworks javascript para tiempo real que van haciendo fallback en tecnologías de acuerdo a si el navegador soporta websockets, server sent events, etc.

Comment: @Hewbot Para ser exactos pooling is el unico fallback que hace en caso que no encuentre WebSockets. Pooling es lo mismo que intentabas hacer al principio. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, y gracias por la explicación, ahora entiendo cómo actúa internamente. ¡Muy buena sugerencia la de Socket.io!

Answer (score 2):

El método que conviene usar es `spawn` en vez de `exec`, ya que el segundo espera a que el comando finalice (y eso es lo que querés evitar).

El stdout *(de child_process)* es un stream readable (de lectura) y el response (de http) es un stream writable (de escritura), así que lo que te está faltando es un pipe (tubería, pero en la consola es más conocido como `|`).

El código sería algo así como:

```
var http = require('http');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  spawn('cat', ['streamout.js']).stdout.pipe(res);
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('server running on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

Si en el medio querés hacer algún tipo de procesamiento, lo vas a tener que hacer utilizando estos mismos streams: `stdout.pipe(colorize).pipe(beautify).pipe(res)`.

Las dos lecturas que te puedo recomendar son (ambas en inglés desafortunadamente): [stream-handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook), [Some Libraries I use to build web-apps](http://substack.net/some_libraries_I_use_to_build_webapps) ambos de Substack. En el segundo hay muchas librerías que te pueden servir para modificar el stream.

Comment: ¡+1 por las recomendaciones!

Comment: Me devuelve que `Object  has no method 'pipe'`, ¿sabes por qué podrá ser?

Comment: Ahí estoy mirando, `exec` no te devuelve los streams hasta que el comando termina, al parecer el método es [`spawn`](http://devdocs.io/node/child_process#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), ahí corrijo la respuesta.

Comment: Tú respuesta funciona sin problema, aunque creo que el enfoque de @devconcept es mejor por la sencilla razón de que no requiere de mantener la página cargando hasta que el comando termina de ejecutarse, y por lo tanto está a prueba de desconexiones intermitentes. Por cierto, ¡muy bien visto lo del `pipe`, lo tendré en cuenta a partir de ahora!